# wordpress shortcode query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a system admin, and I have very little knowledge in php, hoping to find help here.

I have the following shortcode from my wordpress blog

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => array('page'),
        'showposts' => $limit,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => $order
));
```

Currently this shortcode is listing all pages, there is a way that I could set in the array specific page IDs?

Comment: One of my favourite pages at WordPress.org: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $include = array(1,3,8,98,13);
 $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => array('page'),
            'showposts' => $limit,
             'post__in'=>$include,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'order' => $order));
```

where `$include` is an array of the pages you wish to include.

Comment: Thank you, but where should I specify page ids? lets page ID 10,11 and 12. 

thanks again

Comment: You can specify the page id in $include.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type' => array('page'),
    'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ),
    'showposts' => $limit,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
```

If you need more help you can search [in wp_query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Comment: Thank you, it works, is there is a way that I could specify page ids from wordpress page or post? example, I write the short code in page body, then say for example page_id="2,5,12,14,20"

Comment: That would work for any post type.Just add the post type to the post_type array